# how to do css div pop up scrollable using only javascript?

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup

I want to display some text in a **inline popup** window with ok/close button.

I implemented and bit modified [Custom Alert](http://slayeroffice.com/code/custom_alert/) but sometimes the text has too many lines so I need the window **scrollable**.

I want to use only **javascript**. No framework nor libraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should be able to accomplish that with css

With the default style it would be like this:

```
#alertBox p {
    font:0.7em verdana,arial;
    height:50px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-left:55px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/esMde/).

Also as Casablanca points out, if you want to assign a specific class you can modify the javascript to use

```
msg.className = 'messageBox';
```

and then your own css

```
.messageBox{
  overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: Just to complete the answer: in the code that the OP linked to, there's a `msg` element that displays the text, so doing `msg.className = 'someDiv'` would link that element with the above CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the help, updated the answer with your comment.  Thanks again!

Comment: thank you guys. Exactly what I wanted. One more question or should I create new question for that? How can I make the window movable via mouse?